# Looping within a Stored Procedure and filling in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Aim:  To select Properties and show in Gridview based on specific factors/permissions

Error/Issue:

I need to 'loop' to show only the valid properties for the user in the Gridview

Code in SQL

```
USE [database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:        <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description:   <Description,,>
-- =============================================
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSafeguardingActionPropertyByPermission]

@RegionID bigint
,@EmployeeID varchar(max)
,@PropertyID varchar(max)

AS

BEGIN

-- Easier one first
--Head Office, they see all

If @RegionID = 1  --then  -- Head office users
      BEGIN
      SELECT TblA.PropertyID as PId, TblA.Propertyname as PNa, TblB.FireSafety as FireSafety1, TblB.DisplayScreenEquipment as DSE  
      FROM TbPropertyDetails as TblA inner join TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding as TblB on TblA.PropertyID = TblB.PropertyID 
      WHERE TblA.RegionID > 0 and TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertyID + '%'
      END
ELSE  
--Regional Manager who is not Region 1 (Head office) 
If @PropertyID = 99 --then

BEGIN 
      ---- First we want to see what properties the employee has permission to view
      -- Note @RegionID is used here to filter              

      SELECT TblA.PropertyID as PId, TblA.Propertyname as PNa, TblB.FireSafety as FireSafety1, TblB.DisplayScreenEquipment as DSE  
      FROM TbPropertyDetails as TblA inner join TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding as TblB on TblA.PropertyID = TblB.PropertyID 
      WHERE TblA.RegionID = @RegionID and TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertyID + '%'    
END 

ELSE


--Not regional manager so only has access to specific sites
If @RegionID > 1 and @PropertyID <> 99 --then
--99 means they are not a regional manager

      BEGIN 
      ---- First we want to see what properties the employee has permission to view
      SELECT EmployeeID, PropertyID as tbPD_PropertyID 
      FROM tblPropertyViewPermissions
      WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID 

      --loop here?? to get only those the user has access to
      SELECT TblA.PropertyID as PId, TblA.Propertyname as PNa, TblB.FireSafety as FireSafety1, TblB.DisplayScreenEquipment as DSE  
      FROM TbPropertyDetails as TblA inner join TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding as TblB on TblA.PropertyID = TblB.PropertyID 
      -- END here??
      -- what to do here???!!! 
      -- Need to filter by PropertyID(s) that the user can see
      WHERE TblA.RegionID > 0 and TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertyID + '%'                  
      END

END


      -- If SQL can/ can not have If else (????) then capture all and show nothing with error message?
```

Code in ASPX - I have seen SessionParameter which I have always used but I have also seen Control Parameter

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GWmySQL %>"
  SelectCommand="spSafeguardingActionPropertyByPermission"
  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

  <SelectParameters>    
    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="EmployeeID"
      SessionField="EmployeeID" Type="string" />
    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="PropertyID"
      SessionField="PropertyID" Type="string" />
    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="RegionID"
      SessionField="RegionID" Type="string" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `END` which closes the very first `BEGIN` at the start of the sproc

Comment: Thank you! Second pair of eyes. I will edit above now

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "loop to show valid properties for the user"... are you asking how you allocate a value to the `<SelectParameters>` items?

Comment: For the third SQL statement I need to select which properties the user can see and based on these Properties IDs I need to Show fields from both tbPropertyDetails and tbPropertyDetailsSafeGuarding. i.e. If I was doing this on an ASPX page I would loop around based on where PropertyID = vPropertyID but I do not believe I can do this in SQL Stored Procedure

Comment: Ah, I see.  Unfortunately without a good understanding of your table structure and the data it can hold, it's going to be difficult for anybody here to answer that  (and moments after writing that, somebody answers it... I will leave you to deal with GarethD, who appears to have a good idea what you need)

Comment: If  we strip it to a basic Table A, B, C will that help? So we say UserID allowed PropertyID 1 and 2 based on Table A. Given those details now go into Table B and Table C and display these Properties and the fields I request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45288/discussion-between-indofraiser-and-freefaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you don't need a loop, you can do this with a single query:

```
SELECT  TblA.PropertyID as PId, 
        TblA.Propertyname as PNa, 
        TblB.FireSafety as FireSafety1, 
        TblB.DisplayScreenEquipment as DSE  
FROM    TbPropertyDetails as TblA 
        INNER JOIN TbPropertyDetailsSafeguarding as TblB 
            ON TblA.PropertyID = TblB.PropertyID 
WHERE   TblA.RegionID > 0 
AND     TblA.PropertyID LIKE '%' + @PropertyID + '%'  
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    tblPropertyViewPermissions AS pvp
            WHERE   pvp.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID    
            AND     pvp.PropertyID = TblA.PropertyID
        );
```

The final EXISTS clause just does a check to see that the user has permission to view the propery passed as a parameter.

Comment: I think that will work, I need to get my head around it and will mark or comment as soon as I can.

Comment: Should I be using Control or Session Parameters with this?

Comment: I suspect you should be using session parameters for EmployeeID (assuming this is the current user?) then a Control Parameter for Region ID and Property ID (Assuming these are selected by using a control on the page?)

Comment: Great, I'll have a go this afternoon. I will either mark as answer or come back. I have client meetings over the next few days so apologies if I go quiet!